# How to add a font awesome icon next to the post date in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I am trying to add a font awesome icon next to the post date in my wordpress theme. The problem is I do not know how I should add the following line:

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I think I need to add the above line to

```
$time = '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>' ;
```

so that when I call $time later in

```
if ( is_home() ) {printf( $time);}
```

it shows the icon next to the date.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered combining your html and php?

```
$time = '<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' . '<time datetime=' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '>' . get_the_time('j F Y') . '</time>'
```

You can put the icon on either side.

Comment: It works, thanks. Does putting i tags within single quotes incorporate the html code with the php here?

Comment: What if I wanted to add a text like "posted on" to the beginning of the date, right after the title?

Comment: I would maybe use a span or p element just before the i element inside the same single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to make it translatable. Should I use _( 'posted on', 'my-text-domain' )?